# Xcode 3.2.3 STILL does not mark unit test assert failures in the editor

Tags: unit-testing, xcode

I asked this question before and now the problem seems to have returned with Xcode 3.2.3. When I run unit tests and I get an assertion failure I don't seem to get the little message bubbles in the left gutter like I used to. I can hit Cmd+plus to highlight the errant assert and get a partial status at the bottom of the window but I don't see an easy way to get the full assertion failure without digging through the build results window. has anyone else seen this? Did I miss a setting or config ption? What's going on? Other compile errors still show the message bubbles. Help!

Comment: Having the same issue in Xcode 3.2.4 and been wondering how to "fix" it too. Thanks for the cmd+plus shortcut, didn't know that one.

Comment: Yeah the whole writing tests for mobile development is a pain. Everywhere I go it looks like there are intentional roadblocks! As if someone doesn't want me to succeed in using agile.

Answer (score 1):

### Symptom

I'm setting up a project in Xcode 4.2.1. After moving the unit test subdirectories to where I want them I'm seeing precisely the same problem you describe.

A freshly generated logic test target didn't have this problem. I was able to isolate the difference to "../" relative pathing showing up in the build results for my unit test source files. Their presence appears to mess up how line numbers are parsed for marking things in the editor for unit tests.

When I change the *Location* setting for a failing unit test source file from **Relative to Group** to **Absolute Path**, it removes the ".." from the build results and the problem goes away.

Frustrating since absolute pathing is not a viable (portable) solution.

### Possible Work-Around

You could place your unit test files in some subdirectory at or below the directory where your Xcode project is. Xcode does this when it creates a new unit test target. With this constraint, the relative paths to the unit tests don't require any "..".

But this is also annoying. I can think of a few reasons why someone might not want the Xcode project file sitting at the root of their repository.

Comment: I have't seen this problem since I posted it but your answer is very thorough and makes sense. I'll give it a shot when I have a spare moment. Thanks! :)